# Why do only some terminals get a pts

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, lxterminal

When I try to use `write` to talk to users logged into an X session results vary depending on which terminal they are using. Gnome terminal can pick up `write`s, but neither lxterminal nor terminator can. The reason is that lxterminal and terminator don't have associated pts devices:

With lxterminal(s) running:

```
$ who
tshaw    tty7         2013-01-27 21:34
```

With Gnome terminal running:

```
$ who
tshaw    tty7         2013-01-27 21:34
tshaw    pts/1        2013-01-27 22:25 (:0)
```

(the tty7 entry in the above is the X session)

Is there a way to configure other terminals to take pts devices or would that have to be done in source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Original question

All of the mentioned programs have a [`pts`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pts&sektion=4&apropos=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&locale=). The problem is not that your specified terminals don't have a pts device but that the information isn't recorded.

### Why doesn't lxterminal or other terminals show up in `who`

`who` retrieves it information from a [`utmp`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=utmp&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en) file, typically `/var/run/utmp` and is written to by programs themselves. In order to write an `utmp` entry programs have to have access to the file which normal, standard applications like lxterm or urxvt don't have.

### Allow access to `/var/run/utmp` for applications

Typically `/var/run/utmp` is not write-able for the normal user, i.e. programs can't create new entries as a malicious user could just overwrite the file or write fake entries.

On my system `/var/run/utmp` has following permissions:

```
$ ls -l /var/run/utmp 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp 3072 Jan 28 08:26 /var/run/utmp
```

that means in order to write to the file you have to have at least to be in the group.

The best solution to give permissions to programs for updating `/var/run/utmp` is changing the permissions of the program so it can update the file. You can do this by setting the group of the executable to `utmp` and set the `setgid` flag which means it will set the group id from the file permissions, i.e.:

```
chgrp utmp /usr/bin/urxvt
chmod g+s /usr/bin/urxvt
```

Comment: I tried what you said and got this message: `This process is currently running setuid or setgid. This is not a supported use of GTK+. You must create a helperprogram instead. For further details, see:

    http://www.gtk.org/setuid.html`.   Maybe this isn't possible with these terminals then. However, I also noticed that permissions/ownership for gnome-terminal are the same as they were for lxterminal in the beginning.

Comment: @ThomasShaw gnome-terminal uses gnome-pty-helper which has the appropiate permissions

Comment: While that used to be true, terminal emulators are now switching to using libutempter which uses a setgid helper to update utmp (on my system `/usr/lib/utempter/utempter`).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas the underlying issue (permission) is exactly the same. vte uses/used also the gnome-pty-helper

Comment: if you try to set lxterminal setgid on a recent system, gtk will complain (<pre>Gtk-WARNING **: This process is currently running setuid or setgid.
This is not a supported use of GTK+. You must create a helper
program instead. For further details, see:

    http://www.gtk.org/setuid.html

Refusing to initialize GTK+.</pre>) and you need to use a helper.